# Google App Engine gunicorn worker timeout in Flask app when loading a large pickle?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, pickle, gunicorn

I have a 350 MB Sklearn pickle file that I want to load on Flask app start up.

I use `_pickle` because it's mentioned in documentation that it has faster load time:

```py
import _pickle as pickle

start = timeit.default_timer()
with open("pickle/pipeline.pkl", 'rb') as f: 
        # ~350MB file
        pipeline = pickle.load(f)
        stop = timeit.default_timer()
        print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

The pickle loads in 5-12 seconds locally but on Google App Engine F4 (1GB RAM) instance, the `gunicorn` worker times out.

Google App Engine log:

```
A 2019-10-20T20:07:55Z [2019-10-20 20:07:55 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14

A 2019-10-20T20:11:02Z [2019-10-20 20:04:14 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14)
```

I tried increasing the worker timeout by adding the -t flag in `app.yaml` file as follows and still doesn't work:

```
runtime: python
instance_class: F4
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -t 120 -b :$PORT app:app

liveness_check:
  initial_delay_sec: 500

readiness_check:
  app_start_timeout_sec: 500
```

I even tried using eventlet and it didn't work:

```
gunicorn -t 120 -b :$PORT app:app --worker-class eventlet --workers 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process of loading a 350 MB pickle data file is taking too long and App Engine thinks your instance has failed. Your container startup time is over three minutes.

You have a problem that cannot be easily solved. The maximum file size is 32 MB (64 MB for Go applications). You are downloading the file to memory, but your instance is taking too long to download it.

Solution: I would use a different service such as Cloud Run where you can embed your pickle data file in the container image so that downloads are not required.

Comment: how would you suggest embedding the file into the image?

Comment: @dendog In your Dockerfile, COPY the file into the file system. The file then will be part of the Docker image.

Comment: Thanks @John Hanley I am doing this but the `joblib.load` call still takes 3 mins to load the file - is there any other way?

Comment: @dendog Your question does not show code for `joblib.load`. Performance is related to instance size. Try larger instance sizes. Note that containers and their file systems are loaded into memory. If you have a 1G instance with a 350 MB pickle file, maybe you are low on memory processing the pickle file. I don't know as you have not provided details on what is being loaded or the processing/memory required.

Comment: this is not my question, sorry just hijacking the threads! My instance is 4Gi and 2 cpu which is the max. I assume there is no other way to increase the speed to load the file :(

Answer (score 11):

Try with `entrypoint: gunicorn -t 0 -b :$PORT app:app` it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem for long-running tasks as well, however, the Gunicorn docs have a somewhat cryptic warning about this setting: "Only set this (i.e timeout value) noticeably higher if you’re sure of the repercussions for sync workers."